# Cannot add javascript to footer

Tags: php

Im trying to paste my javascript into footer and cant figure out.

```
function js_enqueue_search(){
    wp_register_script("search", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/search.js", "", wp_get_theme()->get("Version"), true);
    wp_localize_script('search', 'search_ajax', array("ajaxurl" =>admin_url("admin-ajax.php")));
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "js_enqueue_search");
```

Comment: Is this code in your theme's functions.php file? Check your browser's dev tools. Are you getting a 404 on search.js?

Comment: @DaveRomsey Hello, its in functions.php I'm not even getting 404. It isnt showing at all.

Comment: Woops ok, I missed this on the first read. Your're missing the call to `wp_enqueue_script( 'search');` after it's registered.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Thanks a lot. :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're missing the call to `wp_enqueue_script( 'search' );` after it's registered.

```
function js_enqueue_search() {
    wp_register_script( 'search', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/search.js', '', wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' ), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'search' );
    wp_localize_script('search', 'search_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' =>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_enqueue_search' );
```

Comment: Can I have one more Q please? I'm getting 404 with the AJAX request and can't find out. I got only this code and this JS. ::  let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.ajax);
  }
};

ajax.open("GET", search_ajax.nonceurl, true);
ajax.send();

Comment: This answer might be helpful: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/301736/2807 If not, please create a new question for that issue.